# is there a way ti get Date\time values Online?

Tags: c#, java, date

My Pc is resetting its date time each restart\sleep 
so i want to write an application that sets the time on each boot
is there a way to get the current date time online in C# or JAVA ?

Comment: Why would you want to write your own code for this? Use the Windows Time Service (assuming you're on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice post: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/c-get-nist-internet-time/
It describes in very detail how to achieve what you want :)